# How to prove that $i\pi$ and $ \frac{1}{e^{-\frac{(m+1)i\pi}{q}} -1}$ are algebraically dependent?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> How to prove that $i\pi$ and
> $$ \frac{1}{e^{-\frac{(m+1)i\pi}{q}} -1}$$
> are algebraically dependent? Where $m,q$ are positive integers.

I can prove this, but the proof is very complicated.

Comment: Show that $$\frac{1}{e^{-\frac{(m+1)i\pi}{q}} -1}$$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$.  Then it is algebraically dependent with anything at all.

Comment: How i can do this?

Comment: Can you show that $$e^{-\frac{(m+1)i\pi}{q}}$$ is algebraic?

Comment: yes i can do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following polynomial:

$$
P(x) =  x^q \cdot (-1)^{m + 1} -  (x+1)^q
$$
If you set $x_0 = \frac{1}{e^{-\frac{(m+1)i\pi}{q}} -1}$ then
$$
 P(x_0) =  {x_0^q}\Big[  (-1)^{m + 1} -  (\frac{x_0+1}{x_0})^q \Big]\\
= {x_0^q}\Big[ (-1)^{m + 1} -  (e^{-\frac{(m+1)i\pi}{q}})^q \Big]\\
= {x_0^q}\Big[ (-1)^{m + 1} -  (e^{-i\pi})^{m+1} \Big] = 0
$$
So $x_0$ is a root of a rational polynomial $P(x)$, hence $x_0$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$. The argument finishes with @GEdgar's comment: "then it is algebraically dependent with anything at all."

Comment: Its wrong, because $\pi$ is not rational

Comment: Here is an update. Hope the argument works now.